# Google donut chart not showing number number inside body if only one item = 100 percent

Tags: google-visualization, donut-chart

I am using Google donut chart to show three items, but when one item is 77(100%) and other two is zero, it is not showing its quantity 77 in its body.
If they are 1,6, 70 then everything is fine. I am showing percentage in tooltip, so in my case if one item is 100% then quantity will not be shown.

[First sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSypA.png)

[Second sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koS8k.png)

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't show because the label is in the center of the hole,
by default, you have a white label on a white background

add a color to one or both of these config options...

```
  backgroundColor: 'magenta',
  pieSliceTextStyle: {
    color: 'cyan'
  },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({label: 'Answer', type: 'string'});
    dataTable.addColumn({label: 'Result', type: 'number'});
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['Correct', 0],
      ['Incorrect', 0],
      ['Skipped', 77]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      backgroundColor: 'magenta',
      chartArea: {
        height: '75%',
        top: 12,
        width: '75%'
      },
      colors: ['green', 'red', 'gray'],
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.5,
      pieSliceTextStyle: {
        color: 'cyan'
      },
      width: 300
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: yes you are right, it is showing in middle, by consistency it should show in its body by default as shown in second image in question.

Comment: there are no options for label placement

Comment: As per design I have to show numbers in body not in middle of the chart, see the second image mentioned in the question. There should be something in the grey background in this case.

Comment: I have shown numbers in outer circle, see second image, similarly it should show when only one item is 100%. In that case it is not showing in my case.

Comment: @aditya: are you familiar with how to accept answers?